# dynamic GNOME panel configuration

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-panel, windowing

I have no idea if this exists, but I'll give it a shot.
in GNOME (specifically on Ubuntu, but i believe this persists), you can right click on a panel, and toggle "expand" which centralizes the panel to just the length it needs to be. 
This looks great when your active programs aren't running.

But when you have  a program maximized, there are two openings in the top corners where you can see your background. I find it disturbing.

Is there any way to configure it so that on maximize of a program, the panel will "expand"?
maybe a shell command? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not such option.  You might need to hack a couple of programs to do it.